# Tab 2 10.1 P5100 stuck on starting screen

Tags: samsung-galaxy-tab-2-10.1

Actually I was downloading something when my tab 2 10.1 p5100 suddenly went off. Then the starting screen came up saying,"Samsung Galaxy Tab 2 10.1" and it is stuck there. I tried the factory reset by holding the power and volume down button but the process says done.But still it doesn't come on completely.

Can anyone please give me some advice on how to fix this.

Answer (score 2):

One of first links in google. Try it.

http://www.tips4tab.com/how-to-restore-galaxy-tab-2-10-1-p5113-to-stock-android-4-0-4-ice-cream-sandwich-with-official-firmware-ueblh3/

In short:

You need to download Odin and firmware package. You boot to download mode, open odin on computer and connect your tablet to pc. You select the frimware donlowaded earlier and click start.

If something fails then you can do again power+volume up.

Comment: Link-only answers are discouraged here.  It would help if you could quote the relevant parts in your answers.

Comment: Edited a little bit, I think other will get what needs to be done?

Answer (score 0):

Is there a hard reset hole in which you can stick a paper clip? If so, I'd let the battery die, then charge it back up and press the hard reset button with a paper clip. That's how I got my old android tablet back to life last summer. I've since bought a nexus 7, though, and I'd highly recommend getting a newer android tablet because they have improved tremendously over the past few years.